# Problems using recursion to reverse a linked list

Tags: c++, function, recursion, linked-list

I am requested to write a driver function to call a recursive function.  I was wondering what i need to do in the driver function.

this program is to reverse a linked list.

```
void invert_r()
{
    //This is the driver function for recursive_invert

    nodeType<Type> *p, *q;

    q = first;
    p = first;
    recursive_invert(q, p);
}
nodeType<Type>* recursive_invert(nodeType<Type> *q, nodeType<Type> *p)
{
    //Invert a linked list using recursion.
    //DO NOT create any new node in your implementation
    if(p -> link == NULL)
    {   
        q -> link = p;
        return p;
    }
    else
    {
        recursive_invert(p -> link, q) -> link = p;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Hard to say as long we can't see what `first` is. Otherwise everything looks fine. What specific problems do you get with this code?

Comment: @g-makulik "first" is the first element of the linked list.  i am confused about the use of driver function and how to use it and then call my recursive function...

Comment: the output of the function is that firstly reverse the linked list by iterative method.  and then convert back the linked list by implementing the invert_r() to call the recursive one

Comment: If _first_ is the first element of the linked list I think they have to be members of _nodeType_, so initialization on _invert_r_ function should be made like this: **q = q->first;**

Comment: @Lolito can u further explain why the initialization should be q = q->first; ?

Comment: You have not posted the definition of _nodeType_; it could be an structure of your own or you could be using a library that defines it. In any case I suppose you're trying to use *first* word because it's a property of _nodeType_ structure (this word it's frequently used for a pointer to the first element, as you said), so it should be part of a class and you are trying to use it in its own, like a global variable. Other option it the case you want to swap both variables first element, in this case initilization should be **q = p->first; p = q->first;**

Comment: Since you need to pass (a pointer to) one node and (a pointer to) the next node, you need `nodeType<Type> *p = first; nodeType<Type> *q = p->link;` and probably `first = recursive_invert(p, q);`, don't you?  At the least, you should not casually discard the return value from the recursive function since it is now the head of the list (and if you lose it, you won't be able to get to the start of the list again).

Comment: It seems alright to me except for the fact that you're setting q->link to point to the new first element instead of setting q = new first element. Also, you are not setting link of new last element to null.

Answer (score 1):

```
void recursiveReverse(struct node** head_ref)
{
    struct node* first;
    struct node* rest;

    /* empty list */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
       return;   

    /* suppose first = {1, 2, 3}, rest = {2, 3} */
    first = *head_ref;  
    rest  = first->next;

    /* List has only one node */
    if (rest == NULL)
       return;   

    /* reverse the rest list and put the first element at the end */
    recursiveReverse(&rest);
    first->next->next  = first;  

    /* tricky step -- see the diagram */
    first->next  = NULL;          

    /* fix the head pointer */
    *head_ref = rest;              
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look anything like the OP's code. It's got a different signature and different structure members.

Comment: John it is only for illustration purpose as like an Algo.

Comment: Please note that we expect answers to address the *specific* issues in the question. If you have a very relevant alternative, you *can* consider adding that - but please be sure to address the question and explain exactly why, first.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice, but if you'd add that I think it might be a good answer ;-)